# Deserialize Object with different key value

Tags: c#, api

I want to deserialize data from simple API but i have problem, since one keys can take different types of returned data:

**I. First option - "value" key as simple object**

```
"meta_data":{
  "id": 83487,
  "key": "_billing_invoice_ask",
  "value": "1"
}
```

**II. Second option - "value" key as array**

```
"meta_data":{
  "id": 83490,
  "key": "apaczka_delivery_point",
  "value": {
    "apm_access_point_id": "9993",
    "apm_supplier": "INPOST",
    "apm_name": "Parking",
    "apm_foreign_access_point_id": "NWJ01N",
    "apm_street": "Street name",
    "apm_city": "City",
    "apm_postal_code": "00-002",
    "apm_country_code": "PL"
  }
}
```

I create **meta_data** model and i want serialize data from API to this model

```
public class meta_data
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string key { get; set; }
  public string value { get; set; }
}

public class api_class{
  //some code responsible for getting data from api
  meta_data data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<meta_data>(response.Content);
}
```

When API return "value" as simple object everythink is ok, but if API return "value" as array i got error:

```
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadStringValue(Newtonsoft.Json.ReadType)
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString()
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadForType(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, bool)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject(object, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, string)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateObject(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, object)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, object)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateList(System.Collections.IList, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonArrayContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, string)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateList(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, object, string)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.CreateValueInternal(Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, System.Type, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, object)
    Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.SetPropertyValue(Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConverter, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContainerContract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader, object)
    ...
    [Call Stack Truncated]
```

Actually, I only need the value of the field "value", if it's not an array (just a simple object). Therefore, I modified the model a bit:

```
public class meta_data
{
  public int id { get; set; }
  public string key { get; set; }
  public string value
  { 
    get
    {
      return value;
    } 
    set
    {
      if (value is not string)
      {
        this.value = "";
      };
    }
  }
}
```

However, I am getting the same error.

Comment: I got the idea that I can represent the "value" property as an object type, not a string. However, it is probably not the best solution?

Comment: Your option 1 and option 2 JSON examples are identical.

Comment: @Llama My mistake, thank you for paying attention - I have corrected the code

Comment: Note that value in your updated example is an object (as would be represented by a class in C#) and not an array. If you need to accept both a string and an object, then you'll need to write a JsonConverter for that property.

Comment: @LLama it is not possible check "value" field return from API in setter after save to variable? I suppose that i use `public string value {  set { if (value is not string) { this.value = ""; }; }` during deserialization my program save to variable empty string -> since API return object - not string.

Comment: `if (value is not string)` doesn't make sense since the property is string. `value` will always be `string`.

Comment: But i understand API return string (in first option) and array (in second option). If api would return string in the latter case why is an error thrown and not the object is just converted to string?

Comment: How would you convert an object to string?